# Замена deprecated Action в IntentFilter

Tags: java, android, android-wear

Использую `GoogleApiClient` для обмена данными  между телефоном и android-часами. У меня есть два `Service` для часов и телефона, оба наследуются от `WearableListenerService`.

Этот сервис я прописываю в манифесте таким образом:

```
<service android:name=".google.wearable.WearListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>           
</service>
```

Но обновив `AndroidStudio` мне начало выдавать ошибку:

> AndroidManifest.xml:11: Error: The
>   com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER action is deprecated.
>   [WearableBindListener]

В [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/deprecation-of-bindlistener.html) я нашёл чем можно заменить `BIND_LISTENER`, в качестве примера там приводят следующие строки:

```
 <service android:name=".FirstExampleService">  
   <intent-filter>  
       <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />  
       <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />  
       <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/FirstExample" />  
   </intent-filter>  
 </service>
```

Я попробовал добавить этот фильтр к своему сервису - ошибка пропала, но при отправке сообщения между устройствами они теперь не отлавливаются сервисом.

Мне немного не понятен в этой строчке:

```
   <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/FirstExample" />
```

Не могу понять что  нужно указывать в `pathPrefix` ?
И в чем еще может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Все заработало, прописав фильтр таким  образом:

```
 <service android:name="MyListenerService">    
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
         <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
         <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/" />
    </intent-filter>
 </service>
```